# with asp.net webform, how to have many login url?

Tags: asp.net

in the webconfig you normally have something like

```
   <authentication mode="Forms">
          <forms loginUrl="Logon.aspx" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH">
          </forms>
   </authentication>
```

is there a way to have many pages in the loginUrl ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found out how.

in the webconfig I had to put that

```
<location path="Connexion.aspx">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="?"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you define your concept for wanting this?  This defines the page you wish your visitor to be taken to if they are not yet logged in.  If they are logged in, they would not be taken to this page.  Given that your visitor can only be on one page at a time, having multiple pages seems like in impossibility... unless you're looking for some kind of hierarchy such that if they're not logged in with a specific role they get transported to a different page instead of the standard login.

Either I'm misunderstanding your intention for wishing to do this or you are misunderstanding how this mechanism works and what it is used for.

Comment: I simply need to have a login.aspx when it's english and connexion.aspx when it's french and if it's possible, to make it work with asp.net webform routing

Comment: I will add that I'm trying to make it work without querystring, I'm using the routename from webform routing to find out which language it is.

Comment: Okay, I suppose that is a valid reason.  I hadn't considered that.  Would you not have all your pages built as templates with just your labels being translated to the alternate languages?  This way you could provide translations without having to rebuild your site each time?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a login page for each language, consider using localisation - you can set up your sever controls (labels etc.) to show text in any language depending on the browser's culture info (I think it's culture info), meaning one page can display any language you care to set up.

A quick Google search:

http://www.asp.net/learn/Videos/video-40.aspx